# mail sending with network credential as true in windows form not working

Tags: c#, winforms, smtpclient

I want to do an application for sending emails in C# windows application.I used smtp server,but I don't want to set the network credentials. So I set it as true.but am getting error.

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   Learn more at

Here is the code:

```
SmtpClient oClient = new SmtpClient();
oClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
oClient.Port = 25;
oClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
oClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
oClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
oMail.To.Add(txtTo.Text.Trim());
oMail.From = new MailAddress("testmail@gmail.com");
oMail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
oMail.Body = txtBody.Text;
oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
oClient.Send(oMail);
MessageBox.Show("Mail Send");
```

here I set the host as gmail.com,I need to send and receive mails using all email service providers.So how can I set the host and port?

Comment: Are you trying to login to gmail using your windows/AD authentication? You need to use a username and password for gmail.

Answer (score 5):

gmail uses port 587

```
oClient.Port = 587;
```

You may also want to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false and explicitly declare username and password. By declaring it to be true, you are trying to log into your gmail account using your windows credentials.

```
oClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
oClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
```

Also, in gmail security, you will need to allow Less Secure Applications.

Finally, you need to change how your Mail.To is populated:

```
oMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Google may block sign in attempts from some apps or devices when you try to login from some app. You need to go to security settings at your gmail and *enable less secure apps* . So that you will be able to login from all apps. Go to [`Allow less secure apps`](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security) and choose Allow to let less secure apps access your Google account. Have a look at [`this`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) link may useful.