# Sending email using smtp on gmail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send confirmation email to user using smtp provided by google and test in my local machine. I have written the code and supply the settings.

```
SmtpClient client = SiteUtilites.GetMailClient(); 

            MailAddress sender = new MailAddress(coreEmail, coreDisplayName);
            MailAddress receiver = new MailAddress(model.EmailAddress, model.Firstname + " " +model.Lastname);
            MailAddressCollection collection = new MailAddressCollection();

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(sender, receiver);
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = "Hello";
            client.Send(mailMessage);
```

This is the setting I have below

```
String smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
        String smtpUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUsername"];
        String smtpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPassword"];
        String smtpPort = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"];

        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
        sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        sc.Credentials = nc;
        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Port = 587;
```

Do I need my site to run in https ? I just want to test my script in my local machine.

This is the error it gives me

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: Google may block sign in attempts from some apps or devices when you try to login from some app. Check this answer for more details:http://stackoverflow.com/a/32475872/2946329

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are using weak password or using the default credentials.
see following links for more details:

- [[SOLVED] 5.5.1 Authentication Required with smtp.gmail.com](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/23569/solved-551-authentication-required-with-smtpgmailcom.aspx)
- [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)
- [The SMTP server requires a secure connection or...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)
- [Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a sec...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not)