# The message can not reach the email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm trying to build a contact form in my website, I'm using asp.net with C#, when I submit the message it does not reach the Email, is it because I'm using local server? or there are mistakes in my code? I got this error message in the catch section: "Your message failed to send, please try again."

this is the code behind page C#

```
try
{
    //Create the msg object to be sent
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    //Add your email address to the recipients
    msg.To.Add("jasmine.afnan@gmail.com");
    //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
    MailAddress address = new MailAddress("jasmine@gmail.com");
    msg.From = address;
    //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
    msg.Subject = txtName.Text + " :  " + ddlSubject.Text;
    msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;

    //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it
    //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("jasmine.afnan@gmail.com", "*");
    client.Credentials = credentials;

    //Send the msg
    client.Send(msg);

    //Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
    lblResult.Text = "Your message was sent!";

    //Clear the form
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtMessage.Text = "";
}
catch
{
    //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
    lblResult.Text = "Your message failed to send, please try again.";
}
```

this is the exception

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Default2.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\looly\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\WebSite6\Default2.aspx.cs:line 46

Comment: We want to know the correct exception so just remove label inside the catch block.then Wrote exception..Catch(exception ex){throw ex};

Comment: At first glance your code seems OK. Have you configured Gmail correctly? It often blocks sending from apps it considers unsecured. Look if you have 2 step enabled, you might need need to generate an app specific password [SEE HERE](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: Post your exact exception.

Comment: I get $10 if the exception is pretty much `The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`

Comment: I updated the post, equalsk you are right :D

Comment: @AfnanHumdan...Google may block sign in attempts from some apps or devices when you try to login from some app. As I said checking this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32475872/2946329

Comment: @AfnanHumdan check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication

Based on this error.you check the following steps.

- Enter the correct login password.
- To remove 2-Step Verification.
- You have to enable login from other timezone / ip for your google
  account.To do this follow the [click here](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
  and allow access by clicking the continue button.
- Go to security settings at the following [Click here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and enable less secure apps . So that you will be able to login from all apps.