# Why I get error in sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I'm developing a simple login page in c#. I'm implementing forgot password link while clicking the link I need to send an email with random number to the corresponding user.I have the added the code which I mentioned below

C# Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    string username = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, [Password] FROM tbl_Detailstbl WHERE Email_Id = @Email"))
        {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sdr.Read())
                {
                    username= sdr["Name"].ToString();
                    password = sdr["Password"].ToString();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
        mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
        mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Your password is {1}.<br /><br />Thank You.", username, password);
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
       SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com","asfsdfg");
  
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "Password has been sent to your email address.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Text = "This email address does not match our records.";
    }
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
    <fieldset style="width:380px;">
    <legend>Recover Password By Email Or User Name</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>UserName : </td><td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;OR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>`enter code here`
    <td>Email Id : </td><td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailId" runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="Please enter valid email address"
                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic"
                                ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send"  onclick="Button1_Click"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
   
    </div>
    </form>
```

My problem is when I try to send an email I'm getting an error:

> " An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

Comment: already answered exception

Comment: Check the answer @chitra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mail sending with network credential as true in windows form not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475832/mail-sending-with-network-credential-as-true-in-windows-form-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.

- Enter the correct login password.
- To remove 2-Step Verification.
- You have to enable login from other timezone / ip for your google
  account.To do this follow the [click here](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)  and allow access by
  clicking the continue button.
- Go to security settings at the following [click here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and enable less secure apps . So that you will be able to login from all apps.