# Mail not sent using gmail smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Here I want to send mail using gmail smtp.But I shows error

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

on button click insted of sending mail.

html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfrompassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbody" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(txtfrom.Text,txtto.Text);
    msg.Body = txtbody.Text;
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtfrom.Text, txtfrompassword.Text);
    sc.EnableSsl = true;
    sc.Send(msg);
    Response.Write("send");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mail sending with network credential as true in windows form not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475832/mail-sending-with-network-credential-as-true-in-windows-form-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn on this option

u can send mail using STMP

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

You can use port 25

```
 SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);
```