# Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am using following code to send email.when i am tring to send mail i am getting the error message

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.txt, to.txt, subject, body);
SmtpClient clint = new SmtpClient();
//for determile email smtp...
string x = from.txt;
int startIndex = x.IndexOf('@');
int endIndex = x.LastIndexOf('.');
int length = endIndex - startIndex;
string xx = x.Substring(startIndex + 1, length - 1);

if (xx == "gmail" || xx == "Gmail")
{
    clint.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    clint.Port = 587;
    clint.EnableSsl = true;
}
if (xx == "Hotmail" || xx == "hotmail" || xx == "live" || xx == "Live")
{
    clint.Host = "smtp.live.com";
    clint.Port = 587;
    clint.EnableSsl = true;
}
if (xx == "yahoo" || xx == "Yahoo")
{
    clint.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    clint.Port = 465;
    clint.EnableSsl = true;
}
clint.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
clint.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
clint.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
clint.Send(mail);
MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Email Successfully Send", "Success",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

and also how can attach any file to this email

Comment: username should be full email address. are you?

Comment: Enable two-factor authentication (aka two-step verification) , and then generate an application-specific password. Use that newly generated password to authenticate via SMTP.

Comment: Why don't you just use the SMTP server your service provider lets you use and make it easier?

Comment: If you are testing this code with gmail, you will have to enable access to less secure apps in your google account from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security). Also set `clint.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before `clint.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mail sending with network credential as true in windows form not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475832/mail-sending-with-network-credential-as-true-in-windows-form-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

For the error you got, I read online that you should use the UseDefaultCredentials before the Credentials line and that EnableSsl of your clint object should be set to true.

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)

> and also how can attach any file to this email

You can by adding an attachment to the mail object :

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filename));
```

I forgot to mention that the double authentication in Gmail might be a problem. If so, refer to the second solution in the link I previously linked.