# When I run this code it gives error at (smtp.Send(mm);) I don't know how to solve it

Tags: c#

This code is giving me some problems when I run it. It does not send the message and it says that the error is on smtp.Send(mm); and I can't solve it

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("eden.elao@gmail.com", Username.Text.Trim());
        mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
        mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Your password is {1}.<br /><br />Thank You.", username, password);
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "sender@gmail.com";
        NetworkCred.Password = "<Password>";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm); // the error is here.
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "Password has been sent to your email address.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Text = "This email address does not match our records.";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your issue has to do with `asp.net` or `sql-server`?

Comment: What is the error? Could you put exception info into the question?

Comment: try port 465 if you are enabling SSL. If you disable SSL use port 587

Comment: Google may block sign in attempts from some apps or devices when you try to login from some app. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475872/2946329

Comment: Don't use google as SMTP, unless you have an enterprise account usually gives a ton of problems. If this is on a web page use your server's SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into a security issue with the smtp server I got it working by providing my real gmail account info on these lines: `"<Password>"` doesn't seem like it would work.

```
  NetworkCred.UserName = "myEmail@gmail.com";
  NetworkCred.Password = "myPassword";
```

And turning on the setting on my gmail account to allow less secure apps to access it.

FYI, for others this was the error before I changed it.

> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
>   or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1
>   Authentication Required. Learn more at