# SMTP gmail on windows application

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I have a problem trying to send email (gmail) it won't allow me to send email if I didn't have the 'allow less secure app' turned on. What am I doin wrong?

```
try

        {

            smtpClient.Host = mServer;
            smtpClient.Port = mPort;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = isenableSsl;                            

            //Input new time out
            if (mTimeout > 0)
            {
                smtpClient.Timeout = mTimeout;
            }
            //Check Authentication Mode
            if (isAuthentication)
            {
                //Create Network Credentail if SMTP Server Turn On Authentication Mode
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = mUserName;
                credentials.Password = mPassword;
                smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            }
            else
            {
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            }


            //Configuration Mail Information
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mDisplay)) mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(mFrom);
            else mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(mFrom, mDisplay);
            mailMessage.Sender = new MailAddress(mFrom);
            mailMessage.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(mFrom);

            //Set To Email Information
            if (ToEmails.Count != 0)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Clear();
                foreach (string mail in ToEmails)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(mail);
                }
            }

            //Set Cc Email Information
            mailMessage.CC.Clear();
            foreach (string mail in CcEmails)
            {
                mailMessage.CC.Add(mail);
            }
            //Set Bcc Email Information
            mailMessage.Bcc.Clear();
            foreach (string mail in BccEmails)
            {
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(mail);
            }
            //Set Mail Information
            mailMessage.Subject = mSubject;
            mailMessage.Body = mBody;

            //Configuration Mail Option
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = mSubjectEncoding;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = mBodyEncoding;
            mailMessage.Priority = mPriority;
            mailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = mDeliveryNotificationOptions;

            //Clear Attachment File
            mailMessage.Attachments.Clear();

            //Add Attachments Internal File
            AddAttachImage(ref mailMessage);
            //Add Attachments External File
            if (attachmentFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                AddAttachFile(ref mailMessage);
            }
            //Link Event Handler
            smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);

            //Send Message Fuction

            SetLogfileSendEmail(smtpClient, mailMessage);


            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            delegate(object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strInformation.Append("(Error) Method smtpClient_SendCompleted : " + ex.Message);
            WriteLogFile();
            throw new Exception("SMTP Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It is also giving me this

> > SMTP Exception: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
> >     The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

I want to be able to send email without having to turn on the "allow less secure app"  option on gmail account.

Is there any other way for third party apps to send emails without having to do 'allow less secure apps' ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475872/2946329

Comment: I want to be able to send email without having to turn on the "allow less secure app" option on gmail account. Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 0):

If you (sender) use gmail provider, try to activate this option

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I want to be able to send email without having to turn on the "allow less secure app" option on gmail account. I edited that on my post. Sorry :(.

Comment: I understand. 
I had the same issue on a school project and the only way to send mail using gmail was to activate this option.

Good luck

Comment: Aww that sucks.

Comment: Is there any other way for third party apps to send emails without having to do 'allow less secure apps' ??